# introducing game center in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in inserting the gamecenter and openfient in my game,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7

through this link, I can't understand that how can I implement gameCenter in my app..

If you have any tutorial then plz share it to me.

Answer (score 0):

You must ask yourself what features you want from gamecenter.. achievements? leaderboards? multiplayer? I assume that you dont like to read wall of texts(me too) but there are no shortcuts..

Very easy to implement.. Just add the gamecenter framework. Click on the frameworks in your project and select existing frameworks to select GameKit and you are ready to use it. Remember to import gamekit as well.

First step is always authenticate the player to check his gamecenter account.. which is in this link: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6)..

Openfeint, they have their own set of documentation.. And you may want to consider openfeint as they have build in gamecenter support as well..

```
[GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
 {
     if(error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"reset");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"failed");
     }
 }
```

Comment: when I use this link [gameCenterManager resetAchievements]; it will only show me  "Missed Method"

Comment: I searched the gamecenter framework and everything is there.. zz.. i have edited my answer to include the reset as well...